# jQuery slider trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I'm creating a simple jQuery slide show. The requirement for the slide is simple, just the slide just flip continuously towards the left. Most of the tutorial shown on line is pretty advanced and fancy. But then I came across one that is pretty much almost what I want.

http://www.webchiefdesign.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-slideshow/index.php

But the problem is when the image slides to the end it will slide backward to my first image. Is there any way that I can change the code so that when the image is slid to the end, the slide will keep on back to first image but not by slide backward.

Comment: Try this: http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Comment: Hi, I have browser through the site. The effect is not what i want to archive. I want the  effect of slide left

Answer (score 1):

If you need to avoid the final slide back to the first and just restart, I would suggest a slight change over Pushpesh's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentPosition = 0;
var slideWidth = 500;
var slides = $('.slide');
var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
var slideShowInterval;
var speed = 900;
var lastSlideReached = false;

slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>');
slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });
$('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

function changePosition() {
    if( ! lastSlideReached ) {
        if(currentPosition == (numberOfSlides-1)) {
            lastSlideReached = true;
        } else {
            currentPosition++;
        }

        moveSlide();

    } else {                     
        resetSlide()
    }


}

function moveSlide() {
    $('#slidesHolder').animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)});
}

function resetSlide(){
    currentPosition = 0;
    $('#slidesHolder').css('marginLeft', currentPosition );
    lastSlideReached = false;

}
```

});​

cheers

Comment: Hi saski,Thanks for the answer. But the effect is not what i wanted. IS it possible that when the slide reach the end. It will back to the first slide but not by sliding backward but keep on by sliding left

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood. Then, you'll need to:
a) clone the #slidesHolder and put it behind the original, when the end is reached
b) ...or move to a carousel component which treat the position of the list elements individually. I'd suggest [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) or [Swipe](http://swipejs.com/), in that case.

Comment: Hi Saski. May be i did not explain clearly. For references http://www.airfares.com.sg/. Their banner will keep on sliding left back to the first slide when it reach the end. i want to create the similar effect for the slide show. I just a beginner for JavaScript so  i didn't know how to do step you posed on the previous post.

Comment: Hi Saski. Its close but i want it to slide by it self not by clicking. Its there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Hi again, you can actually configure it to auto-play, among other options. Have a look to [the docs -options/auto-](http://bxslider.com/options/)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your javascript to this:

**UPDATE:** You want the slider to slide back to the original position once it reaches the slide. This is achieved by the function `slideLeft` once it reaches the last slide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideWidth = 500;
    var slides = $('.slide');
    var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
    var slideShowInterval;
    var speed = 3000;
    var lastSlideReached = false;

    slides.wrapAll('<div id="slidesHolder"></div>');
    slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });
    $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

    function changePosition() {
        if( ! lastSlideReached ) {
            if(currentPosition == (numberOfSlides-1)) {
                lastSlideReached = true;

                            clearInterval( slideShowInterval );
                slideLeft();
            slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
            } else {
                currentPosition++;
            }
        } else {
            if( currentPosition == 0 ) {
                lastSlideReached = false;
            } else {
                currentPosition--;
            }
        }

        moveSlide();
    }

    function moveSlide() {
         $('#slidesHolder').animate(
            {'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)}
         );
    }

function slideLeft() {
    $('#slidesHolder').animate({'marginLeft' : 0});
    currentPosition = 0;
    lastSlideReached = false;
}
});
```

I've added a variable `var lastSlideReached = false;` and made some changes to the function `changePosition`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Pushpeh,Thanks for the answer. But the effect is not what i wanted. IS it possible that when the slide reach the end. It will back to the first slide but not by sliding backward but keep on by sliding left

Comment: Hi Weng, do you want the slider to continuously slide to the leftmost point once it reaches the end and start again. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Hello, i have modified the answer. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Hi Pushpeh. May be i did not explain clearly. For references http://www.airfares.com.sg/. Their banner will keep on sliding left bac to the first slide when it reach the end. i want to create the similar effect for the slide show

Comment: And to be more clear i only want to create a left sliding slide show..it need to be slide by itself. and keep on sliding